# Why is pcap_dispatch only returning 1 packet?

Tags: python, c, pcap

Why is `pcap_dispatch` (with `count`=10) only returning 1 packet?

If I don't do anything it waits and then shows 1 packet, but if I click on a link it stops immediately and shows 1 packet.

Am I supposed to have a loop like this or not?:

```
for i in range(0,10):
        p.dispatch(10, savePacket)
```

This is python, but I had the same problem in C.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

```
       pcap_dispatch() processes packets from a live capture or ``savefile'' until
       cnt  packets  are processed, the end of the current bufferful of packets is
       reached when doing a live capture, the end of the ``savefile''  is  reached
       when  reading  from a ``savefile'', pcap_breakloop() is called, or an error
       occurs.  Thus, when doing a live capture, cnt  is  the  maximum  number  of
       packets  to  process  before  returning,  but is not a minimum number; when
       reading a live capture, only one bufferful of packets is read at a time, so
       fewer  than cnt packets may be processed. A value of -1 or 0 for cnt causes
       all the packets received in one buffer to be processed when reading a  live
       capture,  and causes all the packets in the file to be processed when read‐
       ing a ``savefile''.
```

Note the bit that says: *"so fewer than `cnt` packets may be processed"* - i.e. it's up the the pcap implementation what it does.

A note on Python: I have no idea what the python implementation does, but in C the callback is called for once for each packet anyway.

Comment: The underlying OS packet capture mechanism, atop which libpcap runs, may deliver packets one at a time or deliver them in batches.  `pcap_dispatch()` typically processes one batch at a time - i.e., the number of packets that a single blocking operation will provide - so it may only provide one packet ("one at a time" being one-packet batches) or more, but it won't keep providing them indefinitely.  Use `pcap_loop()` for that.